# Radix Sort with Counting Sort

Tags: java

I'm trying to use **radix sort** to sort 300 random numbers, which are in the format of `SSN numbers`. Every time I use this code I keep getting index out of bounds error. I would like to know what is the best way to solve my problem.

```
public void countingSort(int[]A, int k){

    int []B=new int[300];

    int[]C= new int[k];

    for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
        C[i]=0;
    }
    for(int j=1;j<A.length;j++) {
        C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]+1;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<k;i++) {
        C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1];
    }
    for(int j=A.length-1;j>0;j--) {
        B[C[A[j]]]=A[j];
        C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]-1;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<300;i++) {
        System.out.println(B[i]);
    }
}

public void RadixSort(int []A, int d) {
    for(int i=1;A[i]>0;i*=10) {
        countingSort(A,d);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is SSN numbers?

Comment: Social Security Number(Format= 302-32-9946)

Comment: have got answer (here down)?

Answer (score 0):

At least two bugs are in your code:

1. parameter k > max ssn
2. i < A.length
   Those both are responsible of "index out of bounds error". You can implement this in other way or according to your requirement. Also be aware of your hard coded stuff like size = 300

   ```
   public static void countingSort(int[]A, int k) {

       int []B=new int[300];

       int[]C= new int[k];

       for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
           C[i]=0;
       }
       for(int j=1;j<A.length;j++) {
           C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]+1;
       }
       for(int i=1;i<k;i++) {
           C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1];
       }
       for(int j=A.length-1;j>0;j--) {
           B[C[A[j]]]=A[j];
           C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]-1;
       }
       for(int i=1;i<300;i++) {
           System.out.println(B[i]);
       }
   }
   ```

//i < A.length

```
public static void RadixSort(int []A, int d) {
    for(int i=1;i< A.length && A[i]>0 ;i*=10) {
        System.out.println("My d: "+d+ "i: "+i);
        countingSort(A,d);
    }
}
```